# Automatic F# to C# translation

Tags: c#, f#, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I was wondering if there's any automatic conversion of F# code to C# code that works well in practice. The reason for this is that we have a fair bit of logic in F# which we would like to use with Mono for Android, MonocMac, MonoTouch... to create an app for each platform. As those don't support F# directly it woould be nice if we could continue programming the logic in F# and do the GUI part with C# and those tools.

Anyone knows of something? Thanks.

Comment: Don't support F# directly but F# dll's and exes should work with those platforms too.  Have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need to translate the code? A compiled managed binary should work well with Mono. Just add it to the project.

You can use a tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile your code into another language, but that doesn't really change much - that's the whole point of compiling different languages into .NET CIL.

Comment: skolima, are you sure you can add a binary to a MonoTouch project and will run ok? Keep in mind these frameworks have different limitations that mono itself.

Comment: Yes, I've seen a demo where a F# binary was run on the iPhone via mono touch. There are some limitations, basically you need to be able statically resolve everything, but you can hit them in both C# and F#. The limitations are document here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations

Comment: @Robert, I'll try and look for that demo, it'd be nice. About the limitations part, the problem I think is that F# by its nature is more difficult to statically resolving everything. Will have a look at those cases then. Thanks a lot, very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Any .NET decompiler which supports both F# and C# can do it.

For example:
[Cecil.Decompiler](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Steve Gilham has some good articles about decompiling F# to C# using [Cecil.Decompiler](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2011/02/cecildecompiler-and-f.html) and  [ILSpy](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2011/02/ilspy-and-f.html) and some other blog posts about interoperability between F# and C# code. Those articles may be helpful for you.

Normally, I only use `ILSpy` when I wonder what's going on under F# code, which will be more explicit when decompiled to C#. Compiling F# code into a separate dll and consuming it in your C# code is the best way to go.

Comment: Aren't there any problems in practice? F# is a huge time saver and if we have to tweak some things later in the process it's ok, just as long as they are not headaches... thanks.

Comment: The C# code generated by ILSpy would be unlikely to compile since any use of closures in F# would generate inner classes with names that aren't valid C#.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you should be able to run your F# code on MonoTouch and Mono for Android. In practice...things are more complicated. :-)

MonoTouch and Mono for Android provide their own base class libraries which are incompatible with desktop .NET (they're largely a superset of Silverlight). In order to get your F# code running under MonoTouch and Mono for Android, you must first compile your F# code against the appropriate assemblies.

Furthermore, you'll need to either remove all dependencies on `FSharp.Core.dll` (is that even possible?) or port `FSharp.Core.dll` so that it can execute against the equivalent MonoTouch and Mono for Android assemblies. I'm sure this is possible, but I have no idea if it's been done or how easy this would be.

Once you have either removed or fulfilled the `FSharp.Core.dll` and related dependencies, you should be able to just add all the required assemblies (your F# assembly plus dependencies) to the project and run.

Answer (score 4):

Just found these blog posts by an F# and all things Mono guy: [MonoTouch & F# P I](http://7sharpnine.com/posts/monotouch-and-fsharp-part-i/) and [MonoTouch & F# P II](http://7sharpnine.com/posts/monotouch-and-fsharp-part-ii/)

Comment: Thanks for putting those up to help and improve the answer. Apart from that, Miguel de Icaza has commented they are working on bringing F# to Xamarin (http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5251413) so that's great news and would put F# on a whole different level.

Comment: @JacoboPolavieja A few months ago, an F# MonoGame template was added. So there's that.

Comment: Since Xamarin now supports F#, it is exciting to see we can have F# apps everywhere: all desktops, web, iOS, Android... it's incredible how, being a language that's still not used much, it can target so many different platforms. It's just great :).

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that F# will get more attention for this!

Answer (score 3):

Just compile your F# library with --standalone (Properties | Build | Other flags | --standalone) and it will incorporate FSharp.Core.dll into your library.